# add fees on cart with attribut and quantity

Tags: attributes, product, addition, product-quantity, fee

I would like to add additional fees to Woocommerce. If in the cart we have few products with attribute "consigne", fees of only one product_ID are returning. How to correct the problem ? (Sorry for my imperfect English :-D)

```
function woo_add_cart_fee(){
global $woocommerce;

if(is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
    return;

//Initialisation of costs
$consigne = 0.5;

//cart
$cart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
foreach($cart as $product)
{
    $the_product = get_product($product['product_id']);

    //fee - products
    $nb_products = $product['quantity'];
    $activation_cost += ((float) $the_product->get_attribute('Consigne')) * $nb_products;
}

//intergration fees

if( $activation_cost >= 0 )
{
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee("Consigne", $consigne*$nb_products, true, '');
}

}
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee');
```

Comment: Hello to the SO forum. Please note that this is English (only) forum so please update your question language accordingly.

Comment: thank you for your comment, i check it

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, it looks like `$woocommerce->cart->add_fee()` is only called once because it's not inside your `foreach` loop?

Comment: Thanks Amos,but I'm sorry, I am not an expert, I don't understand how to modify the code

Comment: Hello, I found the solution :

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

' function woo_add_cart_fee(){
    global $woocommerce;

```
if(is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
    return;

//Initialisation des coûts
$consigne = 0.5;

//Parcours du panier
$cart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
foreach($cart as $product)
{
    $the_product = get_product($product['product_id']);

    //Frais d'activation, un coût par produit
    $nb_products1 = $product['quantity'];
    $activation_cost += ((float) $the_product->get_attribute('Consigne')) * $nb_products1;
    if(  $activation_cost >= 0  )
    {
        $nb_products = $nb_products + $nb_products1 ;
    }
}

//Application des coûts calculés

if( $nb_products >= 0 )
{
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee("Consigne", $consigne*$nb_products, true, '');
}
```

}
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee'); '